# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql, smo

- OS : Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Version: 2.0.50727.42

Doing: creating Tables...

> Rec: system.m.FileNotFoundexception: could not load file or assembly
>   'microsoft.sqlserver.smo, version=10.0.0.0, culture=neutral File name:
>   'microsoft.sqlserver.smo, version=10.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' at
>   claimsure.Forml.Runsqlscript(string connstring, streamReader sr) at
>   myapp.Forml.bw_Dowork(object sender, DoworkeventArgs e) 'MN: Assembly
>   binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure
>   logging, set the registry value
>   (NKLm\software\microsoft\Fusion!enableLog] (DwoRD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   (NKLm\software\microsoft\Fusion!enableLog).

I get the above error when running my application on a Windows 2003 server with SQL Server 2005.

I know there is a solution to download SQLServer2005_XMO from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793

I have done this, but after the install a server reboot is required, which is not feasible for the time being.

I need to make use of the server object.

```
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;  

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
            server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 2400;
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlString);

        }
```

Is is possible to load the dll in the same directory as my app and reference it from within the code?

Thanks.

edit: added full error

Comment: What's the full error message? The error message states it couldn't load the assembly, but it will also state *why*. Can you provide it?

Comment: SMO Version 10.0 = SMO for SQL Server 2008 - since you have SQL Server **2005**, you're probably referencing a wrong SMO assembly...

Comment: This has to work on different SQL versions - 2005 -> 2008. I have tested with 2008 servers and it worked, now testing 2005 and get the above. - Not sure how to accomplish this.. Would the using statement pick up the version I have on my dev machine?

Comment: Yeah - but if you install your app, using SMO v10.0, on a server with SQL Server 2005 - where are the SMO v10.0 assemblies?? Do you ship them with your app?

Comment: They are not bundled with the app, but I have access to the server, can I put the dll file on the server/install it without having to reboot the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by building an MSI installer and including all the DLL's required.
Thanks for the pointers.